# reading Struts2 tag values in javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2, tags

I am using struts2 with jsp.  In Jsp, i have a table in which few rows of data are present. I have used iterators to display row data of table. Each row contains a button to update the row data(like priority of row data). 
I am trying to use javascript to update row data when a button is clicked.  I am not able to access the value of button.  I am not able to find which button is clicked (since one button is present for eahc row of data).  I tried using below script.  not working. :(

**function show_alert()
{
    var partnumber     = document.getElementById("stop").Value; 
    alert(partnumber);
}**

Also, please let me know if it is possible to access values of struts2 tag values (which are with in iterator tag).
**Please help me out.**

Thanks in advance. 
regards,
hemanth.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need make the buttons have unique ids.  You can use the iterator's status object to appending the index to the id.

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/iterator.html